# Как найти все class(css) в строке?

Tags: php

Каким образом можно извлечь из строки все class="**class_name**" ?

Не силен в регулярных выражениях, но думаю извлекать все что после =" и до первой "

Буду очень благодарен за помощь с рег. выражением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш [**вариант**](https://regex101.com/r/OtigOv/1) можно существенно [**ускорить**](https://regex101.com/r/UmiPKz/1):

```
preg_match_all('~class="\K[^"]+~is', $str, $arr);
```

---

И кроме этого, не будет захвата ненужных подстрок.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение

```
preg_match_all('#class="(.+?)"#is', $str, $arr);
```